# Can we search the dataextension records

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions

Is it possible to search the data extension for the particular record entry based on different conditions.

The only way that I can see is to export the entire DE and then do a find in Excel.  I hoping there’s a way to search the data extension on the website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can.  One way is to create a View:

[image]

You can now enter whatever criteria you desire.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response @dphil . I am not able to find "View " in our account. We have enterprise email account with multiple business unit

Comment: @CodeDiva You go to the Tab where you would have a list if new accounts and the new button.